# Scale ImageView with border in your content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, imageview

Is it possible scale an ImageView in Android without distort the image?

This is the image:
[image: image to scale]

And I want to scale like this (without distort the border of this):
[image: image scaled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do two things ::

**1]** Using 9 patch images:

- https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example
- https://www.nubeslogic.com/nine-patch-generator/
- https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

This will use your image & transform in 9 patch image..so that the border exceed for portion will be only inside of the view not the border.

2] Building drawble for that..
 - You can use the two drawble for that and use as single unit. for that..

just like ::

For the square simply ::

name ::`square.xml` in the drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/line_color" />
</shape>
```

For the triangle at bottom :: you can use the image for the directly

Suppose its name triangle.png,

then for final the layout ::

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_8">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_20"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_20"
        android:src="@drawable/triangle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/square"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_normal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMyMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Is it possible scale an ImageView in Android without distort the image?Is it possible scale an ImageView in Android without distort the image?Is it possible scale an ImageView in Android without distort the image?Is it possible scale an ImageView in Android without distort the image?"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textColor="@color/black_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please tell if need more assistance